# overcommit_memory and overcommit_ratio

Tags: linux, memory, virtual-memory

Here is my current setting:

```
vm.overcommit_ratio = 50 (default)
vm.overcommit_memory = 2
```

And Current Memory Usage:

```
[localhost~]$ free -g
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:            47         46          0          0          0         45
-/+ buffers/cache:          1         45
Swap:           47          0         47
```

As per the [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Reference_Guide/s3-proc-sys-vm.html) what I understood is:

`vm.overcommit_memory = 2` will not allow to overcommit memory than 50 % of RAM `(as vm.overcommit_ratio is 50)` but still I can see that current memory usage is 46 GB out of 47 GB.

Did I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your documentation link:

> 2 — The kernel fails requests for memory that add up to **all of swap plus the percent of physical RAM** specified in /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_ratio

In your case, you have 47gB RAM, 47gB swap and overcommit_ratio is 50 so a the total memory used can go up to 47+47*.5=70.5gB.

Your currently used memory is 46gB in RAM and 0gB in swap so a total of 46gB which is still under the limit.